# How to make atom autoclose jinja2 tags?

Tags: atom-editor

Can't seem to find a package for this one or I don't know how set the settings right for it to work.
What I want is when I type `{` have atom to create `{% | %}` where `|` is where the cursor goes for typing. I have tried autoclose-html and autoclose-html-plus but it didn't work so I'm not sure if these packages even support what I want or if I don't have the settings right(did not change the settings). Is there a package or an atom native setting where I can state that when I type `{` it autocloses `{% | %}`

Answer (score 0):

What I did and what worked for me is go to Edit->snippets

and then add the following code

```
'.html':
  'jinja2 block':
    'prefix': '%%'
    'body': '{% $1 %}$2'
```

more information can be found on the 
[atom website](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)